# "Repair Disk Permissions" doesn't seem to repair the permissions

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I tried repairing the permissions on the boot disk, resetting the Mac, and repairing the permissions on the boot disk. All times I repair the permissions, the list of the files that needs to be repaired is the same.

What does not allow to repair the permissions? What should I do to repair the permissions on the boot disk? Should I repair them from another Mac?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you're trying to repair permissions? 99% of the times it's recommended, the initial problem isn't one that could even be caused by a permissions issue.

Comment: Since there are some directories that always going to give error messages (without actually causing errors, like nearly all "SUID-errors"), could you give an example on which files aren´t getting repaired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know that your file's permissions are not OK?
What output does your repair permissions print? Any errors?

You could also try running the repair from the command-line if it would make any difference:
`diskutil repairPermissions /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/`

Replace the volumes name.

You could also try running that with sudo or as root, to see if it changes anything.

Edit:
Actually, what you could be seeing is that some application is using the files that "need" to be repaired and thus Disk Utility can't repair them.
Try shutting all applications off and the running the repair

Comment: I know it because when I verify the disk permissions, I get the "Permissions differ on [filename]" error message; when I repair the permissions (either from the terminal or from the Finder), I get the same message, followed by "Repaired [filename]". The problem is that, repairing again the permissions immediately after, I get the same list of files, as if the first time the permissions were not really repaired.

Comment: Yes, I have the same symptom with files that are currently in use. Read my edit :)

Comment: I had that problem with files being in used. The caveat is that if these files are used by daemon/launchd processes they might not be easily terminated. To workaround this kind of issue you can boot the machine from OS X Startup Disk and run Disk Utility from it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [AppleJack](http://applejack.sourceforge.net/) ? it runs at boot time and works for me.